# Interesting puppet show, using multiple techniques, about a prince who visits faerie-land

Tags: story-identification, theater-play

After asking this question about a puppet show I saw in Michigan, I remembered another puppet performance I saw a few years later (around 1987) at my school in Salem, Oregon.  What I remember in this case was that they used multiple different puppeteering techniques to put on the show.

The largest fraction of the puppeteering was done with solid puppets, held by the performers (who were dressed in black and we were instructed to ignore a la Kabuki stagehands or ninjas).  Unlike some artistic presentations we saw in the school gym, this one was done in relative darkness (which was a necessity for some of the puppetry techniques—see below).

A prince on horseback chases after a golden hart and ends up following it into a faerie world (as will happen when you chase oddly-colored deer in a haunted forest).  He has some further adventures there and marries a faerie princess, but I don't recall much else about the middle of the performance.

Time passes differently in fairyland, of course.  One day, the prince has a dream of his father missing him back in the mundane world. They portrayed the dream using a translucent, colored shadow puppet of the prince's father, zooming in and out behind an illuminated screen, giving a kind of eerie effect. This wasn't the only time that they used shadow puppets that way. Most of the major characters in the story also had shadow puppet versions that appeared from time to time. However, the old king, with his white hair and blue robe, appearing in the dream, is the only shadow puppet scene that I actually remember.  (There might have been yet another kind of puppets used occasionally for further contrasting effects—finger puppets, perhaps, but I'm not sure.)

After the dream, the prince says he wants to go visit his family, and his wife tells him (or insinuates, at least) that he will not be able to return to the faerie realm. However, he decides to go anyway. He rides back but finds no one to greet him at home. As he searches the castle where he grew up, he finds a large chest. The puppet character opens the chest so that the raised lid blocks the audience's view of his head while he bends down and roots around and finds a number of keepsakes from his childhood.  After pulling out a number of things, he finds he is getting tired.  He stands back up, and the puppet's head is revealed from behind the chest again: while he was looking at his old belongings, the puppeteers swapped the head on the puppet, so that he is now an old man.

The story, as you can see, followed a fairly common fairy tale plot (like that in "Usheen's Return to Ireland"), so I doubt that it will be possible to identify a specific narrative source for the story, especially since I have forgotten so many of the details from the middle of the play. However, it would be interesting to get some information about the puppeteering company that did the show. There were three performers, I think, including at least one woman and one man.

At the time, the [Tears of Joy Theatre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tears_of_Joy_Theatre) was operating in Oregon, touring puppet shows to schools and other venues, but I don't see anything in the their repertoire that looks right. Nor was it, I believe, the [Oregon Shadow Theatre](https://www.oregonshadowtheatre.com/about.html).  (However, an unrecorded collaboration between the two would fit just about perfectly.)

Comment: As a lifelong Oregonian, I remember this really bad puppet show that they aired on PBS on the weekends.  It was early 80's. It was local and it was literally 2 hands in socks on the back of a couch.  Of course, nothing could EVER beat Ramblin' Rod! lol